# Error in python - object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am not sure what is wrong with my python code:

```
geneid=request.args.get('geneid')
sql=text('select * from INFO where name=:ident')
genes=engine.execute(sql,ident=geneid).fetchone()
params['objs']=genes
if len(genes)==0:
    flash('NO RESULTS')
return render_template('info.html', **params)
```

The error message is: 
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Any suggestion? I would like to show a flash message when there is no result in my query.
I tried also (but did not work):

```
geneid=request.args.get('geneid')
sql=text('select * from INFO where name=:ident')
genes=engine.execute(sql,ident=geneid).fetchone()
params['objs']=genes
if no genes:
    flash('NO RESULTS')
return render_template('info.html', **params)
```

Comment: The full error message surely included a line number.  That might be an important hint as to where things are going wrong, don't you think?

Comment: I did not notice it, great advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are trying to get `len(None)`. What you want is

```
if genes is None:
    flash('NO RESULTS')
```

**Note:** Python does not have a `no` keyword. The closest thing is the [`not`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) operator.