# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() Python on application deployment

Tags: python

I'm just learning python and I'm trying to run my application but get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/plugins/bluegreen.py", line 433, in <module>
    cnames = [bluegreen.get_cname(green), bluegreen.get_cname(blue)]
  File "/Users/plugins/bluegreen.py", line 66, in get_cname
    if len(data.get("cname")) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Here are the contents of line 66 and 433:

66:

```
def get_cname(self, app):
    response = self.get("/apps/{}".format(app))
    data = json.loads(response.read())
    if len(data.get("cname")) == 0:
      return None
    return data.get("cname")
```

433:

```
cnames = [bluegreen.get_cname(green), bluegreen.get_cname(blue)]
```

**Edit 1:**

If I place a print(data), I get the following:

```
{u'entrypoints': [], u'routeropts': {}, u'description': u'', u'repository': u'git@10.10.1.1.nip.io:hello-green.git', u'tags': [], u'lock': {u'Owner': u'', u'Reason': u'', u'AcquireDate': u'0001-01-01T00:00:00Z', u'Locked': False}, u'routers': [{u'type': u'traefik', u'name': u'traefik', u'opts': {}, u'address': u'hello-green.10.10.1.1.nip.io'}], u'deploys': 0, u'routingsettings': None, u'teams': [u'admin'], u'platform': u'go', u'teamowner': u'admin', u'plan': {u'router': u'traefik', u'swap': 0, u'cpushare': 100, u'name': u'autogenerated', u'memory': 0}, u'ip': u'hello-green.10.10.1.1.nip.io', u'owner': u'admin@shipa.io', u'router': u'traefik', u'units': [], u'pool': u'gce', u'name': u'hello-green'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brunoandrade/.shipa/plugins/bluegreen.py", line 434, in <module>
    cnames = [bluegreen.get_cname(green), bluegreen.get_cname(blue)]
  File "/Users/brunoandrade/.shipa/plugins/bluegreen.py", line 67, in get_cname
    if len(data.get("cname")) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

**Edit 2:**

Not sure why I get no cname key, since I'm getting it here:

```
  config = Config.load('shipa-bluegreen.ini')

  app_name = config['name']
  blue = "%s-blue" % app_name
  green = "%s-green" % app_name

  bluegreen = BlueGreen(token, target, config)

  apps = [blue, green]
  cnames = [bluegreen.get_cname(green), bluegreen.get_cname(blue)]
```

Which is reading from the shipa-bluegreen.ini, which I have in the file:

```
[Application]
name: hello
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: `json.loads(response.read())` is returning None. Try printing out the response. `print(response)` just above the line with `data =`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in python - object of type 'NoneType' has no len()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187755/error-in-python-object-of-type-nonetype-has-no-len)

Comment: If I put print(response), I get this: <httplib.HTTPResponse instance at 0x10a552c20>

Comment: @Jortega no it isn't, or else an `AttributeError` would have been thrown earlier

Comment: @user1858059 try `print(data)`, likely, either that key doesn't exist or it is set to `None`

Answer (score 0):

You printed out data, and got

```
{u'entrypoints': [], u'routeropts': {}, u'description': u'', u'repository': u'git@10.10.1.1.nip.io:hello-green.git', u'tags': [], u'lock': {u'Owner': u'', u'Reason': u'', u'AcquireDate': u'0001-01-01T00:00:00Z', u'Locked': False}, u'routers': [{u'type': u'traefik', u'name': u'traefik', u'opts': {}, u'address': u'hello-green.10.10.1.1.nip.io'}], u'deploys': 0, u'routingsettings': None, u'teams': [u'admin'], u'platform': u'go', u'teamowner': u'admin', u'plan': {u'router': u'traefik', u'swap': 0, u'cpushare': 100, u'name': u'autogenerated', u'memory': 0}, u'ip': u'hello-green.10.10.1.1.nip.io', u'owner': u'admin@shipa.io', u'router': u'traefik', u'units': [], u'pool': u'gce', u'name': u'hello-green'}
```

You can clearly see that there is no key called "cname" in here.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I'm not getting cname. On Edit 3, I've posted on how I was expecting to get cname

Answer (score 0):

There's no `cname` key in `data`. `data.get("cname")` returns `None` if the key isn't found but you can specify an explicit default. Use an empty string as the default instead.

```
def get_cname(self, app):
    response = self.get("/apps/{}".format(app))
    data = json.loads(response.read())
    if len(data.get("cname", "")) == 0:
      return None
    return data.get("cname")
```